# Limit mex-function call to m-file in matlab

Tags: function, matlab, mex

Hey there,
assuming I have a compiled mex file with the name 'myMx', is there any way to disallow direct calls to myMx()? I only want myMx() to be called out of my m-file function callMyMx() because that's where I do additional input-arguments checking so that I don't have to do it in the mex-file itself.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make sure that other functions cannot access `myMx`, you have to make it into a [private function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70335.html). Briefly, you create a subdirectory `private` in the directory in which `callMyMx` resides, and move `myMx` there. This guarantees that only functions in the directory of `callMyMx` can see `myMx`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the mex function even more than in Jonas' solution, you could put it in a folder that is off the path, then have your m-file add the location to the path before calling the mex function and remove it afterwards.

Nowhere near as elegant as using a private folder and it will add a computational overhead, but it will make sure that no other function can call the mex function.